Interpolation of .nc file when regridding is returning 'nan' values
I'm trying to regrid the .nc file to upscale the resolution for a random forest model. I am using the xarray.interp for this purpose. For my .nc file only linear and slinear interpolation is working and other method are not working. I was trying to use cubic interpolation since my data has to be regridded to much lower resolution. The .nc file I am working is of resolution 0.05 degree and needs to be regridded to 0.25 degree resolution.
I tried different interpolation method available for xarray. Initially I thought because the 'y' values are not in ascending order, I tried rearranging them in ascending order. But that did not work.
Link to the nc file I am using:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DyrfhVZvueG0yJ8Ca5dON33zga-qw-dP/view?usp=sharing
import netCDF4
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
file_path_nc ="Combined_Day_LST.nc"
dataset = xr.open_dataset(file_path_nc)
regrid_lat = np.arange(21.125,31.875,0.25)
regrid_lon = np.arange(76.125,91.875,0.25)
data_array = dataset.interp(y = regrid_lat,x=regrid_lon,method='cubic')
for variable in data_array.variables:
    print(variable)
which = 'LST'
var = data_array.metpy.parse_cf(which)
values = var.isel(time=0)
lons = data_array.metpy.parse_cf('x')
lats = data_array.metpy.parse_cf('y')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=values.values)
df


Welcome to SO. I'm a little confused. I tried to reproduce the problem, and am unable to. Your data_array output looks like fine to me. Can you tell us what is wrong with it? If I plot it, there are missing values in the bottom right, but this is correct as there is missing data there in the raw data

Hi @RobertWilson. Thank you for your response. The data_array results is returning me with 'nan' values when I change the method to 'cubic'. The above code works only for linear and slinear.
